# trigger insert on same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with field name recordID and users. I created trigger to insert name in the users column when add new record.

```
Recordid  users
xqz       john
```

Now I added new field name usersmodify on same table.
My goal is to insert users modify the record but keep record Recordid and users fields unchange.

```
Recordid  users  usersmodify
xqz       john    david
```

Thank you

Comment: Use a different trigger for updates

Comment: Just to confirm: You're not storing multiple users in a column (e.g. like `john, david, eric`), are you?

Comment: And how is anyone supposed to help without seeing your existing trigger(s)?

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Sample data and expected results would be VERY helpful.  Please see [ask] and [mcve] for additional details.

Comment: Given the information, how do you expect us to help you???  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can certainly do it in a single insert/update trigger. You should be able to place this in your trigger (would need to be a INSERT,UPDATE trigger) with minor modification.

```
--inserts only
UPDATE t
SET users=SUSER_NAME()
FROM TABLE t
inner join inserted i ON i.Recordid=t.Recordid
left join deleted d ON d.Recordid=t.Recordid
where d.Recordid is null

--updates only
UPDATE t
SET usersmodify=SUSER_NAME()
FROM TABLE t
inner join inserted i ON i.Recordid=t.Recordid
inner join deleted d ON d.Recordid=t.Recordid
```

Alternatively, you can have two triggers. An INSERTED trigger and an UPDATED trigger.

However, if you are granting every person a database login, you are setting yourself up for some pain in any kind of scale. My advice would be to pass along the invoking user on all calls as a parameter and set the field from the application and use a single account per application or development team.

Comment: can we create another table for insert modifyuser tracking since I dont feel like to create 2 trigger in same table.

Comment: You can. but it would still be either a single insert,update trigger or two triggers.

Comment: if we use trigger insert to another table then how do I keep  matching recordid from old table along with modifyuser on new table

Comment: @joel the new table would have those columns, but I don't think you should do that. A single row showing who created it and last modified it is quite useful.

Comment: Thank you for your help